# Не возращает string

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

Использую код импорта:

```
[DllImport("Project1.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string summa(string names);

void Test()
{
    Process pr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    Debug.Log(summa(pr.ProcessName));
}
```

Но `Project1` почему-то не возвращает `string` - хотя с `int` работает

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) std::string summa(std::string name)
{
    return "12345" + name;
}
```

Comment: Тип `std::string` не является `c` строкой, используйте `char*`, `const char*` как входной параметр

Comment: @Birdy можете подсказать примерную реализацию с char*?

Answer (score -1):

На С++ примерно так:

```
void Test()
{
    Process pr = ...;
    string s = summa(pr.ProcessName);
    Debug.Log(s.c_str());
}
```

Comment: И как это отвечает на вопрос?